# Scala Mockito Verify method is always Successful

Tags: scala, junit, mockito, verify

I am trying to use **verify** method of **mockito** using **scala** as a language. However for my case verify method is always successful, even if that method is not being called.

Below is the codeline where getDetailsBySkus calls method getPriceAndAvailability just once internally. How can I make this work ?

Below is the code snippet.

**Code:**

```
doReturn(Future(TestConstantsSpec.PNA_RESPONSE), Nil: _*)
      .when(distributorService).getPriceAndAvailability(ArgumentMatchers.any())(ArgumentMatchers.any())

"empty part number" should "not execute calls-1" in {


    purchaseOrderService.getDetailsBySkus(purchaseOrder.distributor, Seq("KJH"))
      .flatMap(output => {

        verify(distributorService, Mockito.atLeast(10))
              .getPriceAndAvailability(ArgumentMatchers.any())(ArgumentMatchers.any()) // successful

        Future(output)
      }
      )

  }

"empty part number" should "not execute calls-2" in {


    purchaseOrderService.getDetailsBySkus(purchaseOrder.distributor, Seq("KJH"))
      .flatMap(output => {

        verify(distributorService, Mockito.atLeast(100))
              .getPriceAndAvailability(ArgumentMatchers.any())(ArgumentMatchers.any()) // successful

        Future(output)
      }
      )

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your test cases are not waiting for the completion of the Futures, if you are using ScalaTest or similar, here's where you can read up on your options: https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/async_testing

Comment: I have tried to wrap-up the code between Await.result(--, Duration.Inf). However outcome is still the same.

Comment: Does `verify` return something or does it throw an exception?

Comment: it returns mocked object.

Comment: So why do you expect the test to fail? You're returning the `output`.